# Read csv into dictionary with 2 keys per values and assign first non-zero number to the dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I want to read a csv into a dictionary with the key being the wellID and months 1-12, and the value be the first non-zero value in the data. My output is only capturing the second month (12) in the dataset:

```
 'Month': {},
 'MUN-1': {12.0: -292.1183432},
 'MUN-42': {12.0: -3566.994083},
 'MUN-57': {},
```

My data looks like this:
[image]

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('wells.csv')
rows = df2.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)

lst = []
for i in rows:
    lst.append(i)

N=1
wellID = {words[0]:words[1:] for words in lst}

names = []
for i in wellID.keys():
    names.append(i)

namesdict = dict()
for name in names:
    namesdict[name]=dict()


timeseries=dict()
dict(itertools.islice(namesdict.items(),N))
idx=0
for month in wellID["Month"]:
    for well in wellID.keys():
        timeseries[well]=dict()
        if wellID[well][idx]<0:
            currentMonth=wellID["Month"][idx]
            timeseries[well][currentMonth]=dict()
            if currentMonth not in timeseries.keys():
                timeseries[well][currentMonth]=wellID[well][idx]
        idx=+1
```

Comment: kindly post your data and not pics. use this as a guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359855/pandas-group-by-field-in-each-row

Answer (score 0):

```py
order = list(map(int, list(df2)[1:]))
answer = {}
for month in wellID.keys():
    index = next((i for i, x in enumerate(wellID[month]) if x), None)
    i = order[index]
    value = wellID[month][index]
    answer[month] = {index: value}
```

Try replacing the last for loop with this !